# Unable to use Idselector in php EOD for jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having trouble with jQuery .click function after I move html table in the middle of php script,
printing out with EOD. It seems Id selector is not working. But I am able to change background color with css. Why won't it function with jQuery? It will be gratefull if anyone could help me with starter coding.

I have one hole script in one html(.php) page, jQuery in Header section,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#refresh_data').click(function(){
      alert("CLICK OK");
    $.ajax({  success: , <...more coding...> fail: <...more coding...>  });

});
```

I have php script written in Body part.

```
<?php
<...more php coding...>
        echo <<<EOD
        <button id='refresh'>REFRESH DATA</button>
        <table id='show'></table>
        EOD;
<...more php coding...>
?>
```

Comment: wrong id name up in description , and i have checked my code. $('#refresh_data').click(function(){ 　→　  $('#refresh').click(function(){

Comment: You can edit the question and add the correct details anytime instead.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by using class. The Button was in loop in between for(){} so id was used in HTML for more than once.